# Which implementation of set does map.keyset() returns, and why it does not support add operation on it?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

Why this is throwing `UnsupportedException`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("a", "a value");
    Set<String> set=map.keySet();
    set.add("b");
}
```

Comment: Javadoc: _" The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa"_  What semantics would you expect from adding a new key to the keyset without providing a value?

Comment: Just create your own Set with the keys of the Map  like this:
Set set = new HashSet(map.keySet());
Then you can add whatever you want to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Map` interface does not define which implementation of `Set` the `keySet()` should return. Specifically, `HashMap#keySet()` returns an instance of the inner class `java.util.Map$KeySet`. The returned `Set` represents the keys of the `Map`, so adding to it would, in essence, mean adding a key to the map. Ultimately, this is a design decision the JDK developers took, but IMHO, it's the right one. Assume this operation was allowed - What would this operation do? Add a key to the map pointing to a `null` value? What if you extend `Map` to perform some operation on the value when it's added? How would such a scenario be treated?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--):

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. **The set is
>   backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set**, and
>   vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is
>   in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the
>   results of the iteration are undefined. The set supports element
>   removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the
>   Iterator.`remove`, `Set.remove`, `removeAll`, `retainAll`, and clear
>   operations. **It does not support the `add` or `addAll` operations**.

The solution would be creating a new set, and add the result to it. But not to the same set you returned from the `keySet` method.

Answer (score 0):

The Addition of element is not supported in the result returned by `keySet()`. It does not support the `add or addAll` operations.It only supports `remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations.`

for more details please read  [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29)